# MSYS make.exe command won't do anything ("Nothing to be done for...")

Tags: c, makefile, mingw, msys

Ok, hello everyone.
I searched a lot to see if I could find an answer to my question, but I couldn't.
I installed the latest versions of MinGW and MSYS on Windows 10.
I created a very simple C file, based on Zed Shaw's guide (Learn C the hard way), which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int distance = 666;

    printf("You are %d miles away. \n", distance);

    return 0;

}
```

Now, according to Shaw's guide, I should be able to compile the file just by using the following command:

```
make .\es1.c
```

And it should automatically recognise that I'm compiling a C source file and use some default options, like "-o es1", even without a makefile.
The problem is that when I try to compile it using MSYS's make, I get this:

```
make.exe": Nothing to be done for `.\es1.c'.
```

And I can't make it compile in any way.
If I call directly the gcc compiler, in this way:

```
gcc .\es1.c -o es1
```

It works.
What I am I doing wrong?

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem maybe is with the schizophrenic interaction of Unix build tools and Windows program execution:

```
user@dogbert ~/foo
$ echo "int main() { return 0; }" > foo.c

user@dogbert ~/foo
$ cat foo.c
int main() { return 0; }
```

So far so good. Now make it - no makefile needed.

```
user@dogbert ~/foo
$ make foo
cc     foo.c   -o foo
```

Although the target was named `foo`, `foo.exe` was made.

```
user@dogbert ~/foo
$ ls
foo.c  foo.exe

user@dogbert ~/foo
$ ./foo

user@dogbert ~/foo
$ ./foo.exe
```

It seems that `foo` and `foo.exe` are synonyms on cygwin.

```
user@dogbert ~/foo
$ make foo
make: foo is up to date

user@dogbert ~/foo
$
```

Comment: No, sorry, I lose you at this point:

$ make foo
cc     foo.c   -o foo

Mine does not do that! it just says: make.exe": Nothing to be done for `.\es1.c'. even the first time ever that I run the compiler on the c file.

Comment: EDIT: yes! you are right, the problem is that I was calling make on "es1.c", the right command is "make es1", without the extension. But now I got another problem: make es1 > cc     es1.c   -o es1 > make.exe": cc: Command not found. I googled it, and it looks like the problem is that the right command for MinGW is gcc and not cc... so why did they do this?

Comment: `cc` is the name of the standard C compiler on a Unix system. You can override it by giving `CC=gcc` on the command line (note the uppercase CC). I recommend you install a full cygwin install instead of MSYS - I think cygwin has most rough edges regarding unixoid behaviour on Windows ironed out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the *target* (what is to be built) to the make command, not the dependencies of the build.  The make tool will always consider non-generated source file as up-to-date because, by definition, there is nothing from which they can be built.

In your case, try this:

```
make es1.exe
```

(I assume you are on Windows and your makefile is set up to create the target with an `.exe` extension.)

Comment: Then you have to show us a minimal makefile which exhibits this problem.

Comment: No, I am not using a make file. According to Z. Shaw's book, if I run "make" without a make file, it should automatically do something like "gcc es1.c -o es1" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3rQTDagTAI at minute 9:55), but mine does not!